# How can I set selectBooleanRadio element to have its label to the left?

Tags: css, jsf, trinidad

According to https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/skin-selectors.html#MiscSelectors,
I have tried to do it through styleClass attribute.

I have already tried to set af|selectBooleanRadio::content and af|selectBooleanRadio::label to left and to right, through float and through text-align, with simple set to false or true - nothing helps.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.SelectBoolean["timeIntervalRadio_referenceConfirmation_radio"]-->
 <span class="{text-align:left} af_selectBooleanRadio" id="timeIntervalRadio_referenceConfirmation_radio__xc_r">
 <span class="af_selectBooleanRadio_content">
 <input id="timeIntervalRadio_referenceConfirmation_radio" title="Reference Confirmation" name="timeIntervalRadio" type="radio" value="timeIntervalRadio_referenceConfirmation_radio">
 <label for="timeIntervalRadio_referenceConfirmation_radio">
 <!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.SelectBoolean["timeIntervalRadio_referenceConfirmation_radio"]-->
 Confirmation reference
 </label>
 </span>
```

And here is the selectBooleanRadio call:

```
       <c:set var="styleClass" value="{text-align:left}"/>
       <tr:selectBooleanRadio
              group="#{groupId}"
              id="#{radioId}"
              shortDesc="#{ib:fn_coalesce(title,label)}"
              simple="#{ib:fn_coalesce(simple,true)}"
              text="#{radioText}"
              styleClass="#{ib:fn_coalesce(styleClass,'selectTimeIntervalRadio')}"/>
```

Comment: @BalusC I have added the html and tr call

Comment: try experimenting with the css float

Comment: ??? No idea what you mean by _"I had, too"_

Comment: @Kukeltje I had tried it, too, thank you. Now I have also mentioned it in the question.

Comment: I see (as text, not as code, so difficult to read) very weird selectors. I doubt they work at all (setting text to read via those selectors would not work either)

Comment: Ahhh special Trinidad selectors that are runtime converted to real css?... if you apply those, check how they end up in the **generated** html... The label should get a float:right (or the input a float:left) iirc

Comment: @Kukeltje I see that they look strange. If they looked well, the page would look as I need. But how need I call these trinidad attributes for not to see rubbish as the result?

Comment: @cagnus: no, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in Trinidad. Your would expect the `label` to be rendered with `af_selectBooleanRadio_label` in the `class` attribute (in development), just like `af_selectBooleanRadio_content` is used in the surrounding `span`.

You can simply work around this by using the following rule in your skin:

```
af|selectBooleanRadio::content label { float: right; }
```

(In development) this will end up as follows in your CSS:

```
.af_selectBooleanRadio_content label { float: right; }
```

Comment: I am starting to feel a hope, but please, could you elaborate your last two non-code lines, please? I do not understand them: where should I put that code line?

Comment: Use the first line in your CSS, it will be translated to the second line when deployed. See also https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/skinning.html

Comment: But I don't want to set the left placement of the label for ALL radio buttons. I want to set it for one element only. So I want to set a style change for this element using tr:styleClass attribute....But thank you for the reference - it is ineresting. (the problem is that while I am doing in JEE my second week, everything seems interesting to me :-)

Comment: In that case simply add a class and use `.yourClass af|selectBooleanRadio::content label { float: right; }`

Comment: By the way, if you are starting with JEE, I would not recommend Trinidad. There is not much active development there and the documentation is still mainly based on the 1.2 version of Trinidad. You could have a look at PrimeFaces or BootsFaces for better documented projects.

Comment: Thank you. But the project I am working on, is old enough. I won't change the technology in the working app that is used by 1.2M people without the very serious reason. And not when I don't understand the current technology.

Comment: I have created a lable before labelless radiobutton. I simply have no time for science :-(

Comment: And  IMHO, creation an API item for radiobutton without a switch right/left is a total nonsense. I would not reccommend Trinidad, either.